# What is the fastest method to copy directory in linux?

Tags: linux, windows, shell, copy, cp

Linux is offering much less copying speed compared to windows.To copy 1GB data in linux it takes much more time compared to windows.So please suggest me to copy directory as effective as windows.I tried using cp,rsync and also changed the file system to ntfs but i did not find any of the above method as good as windows copying speed.

Answer (score 0):

Copying speed heavily depends on underlying file system. Sorther command for copying a directory is this:

```
cp -a ORIGIN DESTINATION
```

Comment: tried using a option too but still not able to files copying only at 10mb/sec

Comment: Which are the underlying file systems? Are they Linux native filesystems? Take into account that for NTFS file systems, most Linux distributions use FUSE file systems, which is a file system user implementation, and so, slower than a Kernel one. Also, this questions fits better in [Super User](http://superuser.com/) than in Stack Overflow, which is for programming practices.